# Why SQLAlchemy not adding auto increment?

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

### Introduction

I am running pytest to perform some database integration tests. I have a fixture which is run for `scope='session'` to setup connection and run migrations for models.

### Issue

Create statements are being run, but, create table statement is missing autoincrement condition.

I have the following model:

```
class MyTable(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'my_table'
    id = Column("id", SmallInteger, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = Column(String(255))
```

I have defined `autoincrement` yet I've read that there is no need to do that...

However, when I run `Base.metadata.create_all(engine)`, the following SQL is executed when I run `pytest -vv`:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
        id SMALLINT NOT NULL, 
        name VARCHAR(255), 
        PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

Comment: I am using sqlite

Answer (score 2):

Sqlite's autoincrementing behaviour only works for the `INTEGER` type - it doesn't work with other integer types (such as `SMALLINT`).

To get the autoincrementing behaviour using SQLAlchemy you must either:

- use the Integer type

```py
    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key)
```

- use TypeEngine.with_variant()

```py
id = sa.Column(sa.SmallInteger().with_variant(sa.Integer, 'sqlite'), primary_key=True)
```

- subclass `SmallInteger` to override the DDL output

```py
from sqlalchemy import SmallInteger
from sqlalchemy.ext.compiler import compiles

class SLSmallInteger(SmallInteger):
    pass

@compiles(SLSmallInteger, 'sqlite')
def bi_c(element, compiler, **kw):
    return "INTEGER"

@compiles(SLSmallInteger)
def bi_c(element, compiler, **kw):
    return compiler.visit_SMALLINT(element, **kw)
```

The final example is untested, but based on the example code in the [docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/sqlite.html#sqlite-auto-incrementing-behavior) for the Sqlite dialect, which discuss Sqlite autoincrementing behaviour in detail.